# Why is this blazing fast then slows to a crawl

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a bunch of photos in S3 for which I have corresponding object detection records and want to download and bin them by category. My script burns through the first few hundred in a couple seconds then slows to a crawl without any indication of a memory leak or bandwidth throttling (that I can detect) or any other obvious reason. It will download 600 photos in about 6-8 seconds, then 1500 in a few minutes, but 24hrs later it only gets up to 1700 and is still running. I can't seem to think of why this could be happening, and I've done similar things before without this issue. I wanted to post the downloader section of my code to see if anyone can spot any obvious issues. Thanks!

```
from utils import record_list
from ast import literal_eval
import os
import urllib2
import multiprocessing
photo_path = '/home/ben/Desktop/neuralnet_photos/photos/'
service = 'source_name_here/'

# Download photo and stuff into corresponding category folders
def downloader(record):
    tags = literal_eval(record[-2])
    for tag in tags:
        try:
            #Checks to see if the directory exists. If false, creates the directory.
            if not os.path.isdir(photo_path + tag):
                os.mkdir(photo_path + tag)
            filename = record[1] + '.jpg'
            url = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/myphotosfolder/'+ service + filename
            photo = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            with open(photo_path + tag + "/" + filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(photo.read())
        except Exception as e:
            print e

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    p.map(downloader, record_list)
```

Comment: A stab in the dark: perhaps Amazon is rate-limiting you?

Comment: What makes you think you're not getting throttled?

Comment: It's coming to a complete stop. And it's my S3 bucket. I don't have any throttling configured, at least that I know of.

Comment: I seriously don't understand why the immediate downvote.

Comment: More processes won't make I/O requests go faster, especially over TCP sockets which block. Not sure what you hoped to accomplish with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Disagree, adding multiprocessing actually did make it go quite significantly faster, before it starts to slow down. I have a high bandwidth connection, overclocked DDR3 and raided SSDs among other things - throughput is clearly not the issue here.

Comment: After reading the Amazon documentation on S3 I can confirm that there is no rate-limiting occurring on Amazon's end.

Comment: Adding more processes actually allows it to download more photos before halting, and faster. This is why I assumed there was a bug somewhere in what I'm doing.